# Import part of MySQL dump (not all of it)

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm going to do some stress tests and right now I have a really really huge MySQL dump file in hand that could be used as the benchmark.

There's only one table inside the dump.

What's awkward is that my server doesn't have that much disk space to actually hold this table. So I would like to just import some random part of the dump, not all of them.

Is it possible? If yes, what does the command line look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL dump files are simply text files full of SQL statements.  Write a simple program to read the dump file and write random parts of it to a new dump file.

Answer (score 3):

I have created a shell script for this. If you are on a unix based system, use
https://github.com/JoyceBabu/MySQL-Dump-Table-Extractor

Invoke the script using `./extract_table.sh sqlfile.sql`

To extract a single table type the table name
To extract all tables from table1 to table2 type `table1 table2`
To view a list of all available tables type `LIST`

Comment: I was working with a 17Gb dump file, and only needed to extract 3 little tables in it... Your script was a life saver for me, you could think about refactor it a little, adding some new little features (like the possibility to extract only a list of tables in separate files), but that's already nice work !

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just manually split the file?  These are just flat text files...so open it up in your favorite text editor and delete half of the file (or however much you want).